# Linux text editor temp files search

Tags: linux, security, find, owasp

I remember reading where it is bad security practice to edit files directly on the server because it may create hidden temporary files. Is it possible to search for these files? I was thinking of find / -name .*, but that returns "paths must precede expression: .." and do not know if that will include all files possibly created by elvis or nano.

Comment: Surely among the security problems inherent in making ad-hoc, unarchived changes to system configuration, the presence of editor backup files is pretty low on the list...

Comment: I am following http://www.slackbook.org/html/security.html#SECURITY-DISABLE

Do you have suggestions on a proper workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the name in quotes:

```
find / -name '.*'
```

otherwise the shell interprets it and runs something like:

```
find / -name . ..
```

Answer (score 2):

I've seen several versions of that "backup" file name pattern but the most common one has always contained a `~`. If you're just looking for `~` then something like this would work...

```
find / -name '*~*'
```

If you want to find hidden files then...

```
find / -name '.*'
```

Comment: Most of them end with a `~`. For those I'd recommend `find ./ -name '*~'`

Comment: @skjaidev: right, but I've also seen name~.extension. I figure, give the OP more than he needs :)